# How to store the generated LLVM-IR code of a llvm::Module to a string?

Tags: llvm

The `Fibonacci`example of LLVM prints out LLVM IR using `errs() << *theModule`.

Is there any function that is able to store the generated LLVM IR to a (vector of) string or any other variable rather than just print it out? (e.g., `std::string llvm_IR = theModule->getIR()`)

I been searching [llvm::Module Class Reference](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html) and get nothing helpful on it.

Part of `Fibonacci.cpp`:

//`CreateFibFunction` is defined previously to generate the `fibonacci` function.

```
LLVMContext Context;

// Create some module to put our function into it.
std::unique_ptr<Module> Owner(new Module("test", Context));
Module *theModule = Owner.get();

// We are about to create the "fib" function:
Function *FibF = CreateFibFunction(M, Context);
errs() << "OK\n";
errs() << "We just constructed this LLVM module:\n\n---------\n";
errs() << *theModule;
errs() << "---------\nstarting fibonacci(" << n << ") with JIT...\n";
```

Comment: `errs()` always returns a static ` raw_ostream` (see http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/raw__ostream_8cpp_source.html), so you can define your own raw_ostream variable `s` and use `s<< *theModule` to write to the stream and then convert to std::string (I remember there is a subclass designed for that).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it the same way -- instead of using `errs()`, which is a `raw_ostream`, you can use a `raw_string_ostream`, like this:

```
std::string Str;
raw_string_ostream OS(Str);
OS << *theModule;
OS.flush()
// Str now contains the module text
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like printing the module text to a stream is external to the Module class. PrintModulePass or similar depending on your version

I'd find a tool that prints the module and see how they do it, perhaps 'opt'.